# Using regextract and importrange together make a "duplicate" formula

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, countif, importrange

I have a spreadsheet where I look if the data (website) already exist on the master sheet.

```
=if(countif(importrange("Spreadsheet Key","Leads!N:N"),K2)>0,"COMPANY EXISTS!","")
```

But the above formula is not dynamic enough. If there are companies with co.uk and on the master sheet if it's registered under .com, it won't show "COMPANY EXISTS!"

So I changed to the formula to look for works after before and after "." on a website.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(UNIQUE(SUBSTITUTE(importrange("Spreadsheet Key","Leads!N:N"),"www.","")), "([0-9A-Za-z-]+)\."))
```

But it's not working if I try to incorporate with if and countif.

```
=if(COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(importrange("Spreadsheet Key","Leads!N:N"),"www.",""), "([0-9A-Za-z-]+)\."),L2:L)>0,"Company Exist!",""))
```

It shows 'Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got 1 arguments'

Can anyone help me out on where I am making the mistake?

Spreadsheet link- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1La3oOWiM5KpzRY0MLLEUQC25LzDuQlqTjgFp-VlS8Bo/edit#gid=0

Edited: Made a mistake beforehand, didn't specify on that cell its looking against

Answer (score 1):

Your formula had a typo. You are not closing the `Arrayformula` and the `Countif` correctly (*the array formula closing parenthesis should go before the `,` of the count if*). So change this:

```
=if(COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(importrange("Spreadsheet Key","Leads!N:N"),"www.",""), "([0-9A-Za-z-]+)\."),L2:L)>0,"Company Exist!",""))
```

To this:

```
=if(COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTRANGE("Spreadsheet Key","Leads!N:N"),"www.",""), "([0-9A-Za-z-]+)\.")),L3:L)>0,"Company Exist!","")
```

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Answer (score -3):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(IF(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTRANGE(
 "1bnz7Y_xVN9Jo80aCBBeMBMJBnMDHkbZQUWnmL20CRi8", "Leads!N:N"), 
 "www.", ), "([0-9A-Za-z-]+)\."))>0, "Company Exist!", )))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking into my question. I apologize as I made a mistake. All of the formulae is looking against a column.
"([0-9A-Za-z-]+)\."))>0 will be "([0-9A-Za-z-]+)\."),P2)>0"

Also, its showing Company Exists for anything non-blank. So it's not working unfortunately

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Keep in mind that even if this code did solve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how/why your code addresses it. This way, future visitors can learn from your post, & apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. High quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. This, plus the requirement that all posts be self-contained, are some strengths of the SO platform that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or supplement your explanations with source documentation.